# Details on the utility `memhog` in Linux environment?

Tags: linux, memory-usage

I'm working on reviewing memory usage on an EC2 instance running the Amazon kernel and ran across the utility `/usr/bin/memhog` but it has no manpage.  Before blindly running, I was wondering what it does and how it use it.

Anyone use this and know what it does?

Comment: Why don't you ask Amazon? It's their distribution after all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd never heard of it before your mention of it. In an article on [SCO Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCO_OpenServer), *[My system is slow (Old Sco Unix)](http://scofaq.aplawrence.com/FAQ_scotec1slow.html)* on the utility, though, it doesn't sound like it is apt for what you want to do.

> Linux systems have "memhog" if numactl is installed. Numactl can
>   assign specific a process to a specific cpu and control memory policy
>   in other ways. The "memhog" does something very simple: it eats up
>   memory and then releases it. Why would you ever do that?
>
> Well, possibly to test how another app performs when starved for
>   memory or to push unused memory in other apps out to swap (that can
>   help you see what's really available should you need it).

Apparently, you provide an argument to the utility specifying how much memory you want it to take, e.g. **memhog 512m** - see *[Issue 19:   crash with repeated cycles of memhog (x86 and x64)](https://code.google.com/p/compcache/issues/detail?id=19)*

Perhaps one of the utilities mentioned in *[5 commands to check memory usage on Linux](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/)* would be more suitable for your purpose.